# Issues with transforming array data

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, data-structures

I'm trying to transform the following JSON array data structure -

#### From

```
[
  {
    "date": "2019-01-01",
    "marks": [
      {
        "quantity": {
          "shoes": 1,
          "belt": 2,
          "socks": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-01-02",
    "marks": [
      {
        "quantity": {
          "shoes": 4,
          "belt": 5,
          "socks": 6
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### To

```
rows: [
  {
    values: [ '2019-01-01', 1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    values: [ '2019-01-02', 4, 5, 6]
  }
]
```

The code that I was able to try so far is this -

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = [
    {
      "date": "2019-01-01",
      "marks": [
        {
          "quantity": {
            "shoes": 1,
            "belt": 2,
            "socks": 3
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2019-01-02",
      "marks": [
        {
          "quantity": {
            "shoes": 4,
            "belt": 5,
            "socks": 6
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  var transform = response.map(function(dailyMarks) {
    var row = [];
    Object.keys(response).asArray().forEach(function (field) {
      switch (field) {
        case 'shoes':
          return row.push(dailyMarks.shoes);
        case 'belt':
          return row.push(dailyMarks.belt);
        case 'socks':
          return row.push(dailyMarks.socks);
        case 'date':
          return row.push(dailyMarks.date);
        default:
          return row.push('');
      }
    });
    return { values: row };
  });
  Logger.log(transform);
}
```

However, I'm running into this error -

> TypeError: Cannot find function asArray in object 1,2. (line XX, file "Code")

Pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but have not been able to figure out where.

Objective is simply to transform the aforementioned data structure - approach doesn't really matter.

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what `.asArray()` is. I've never heard of that method before. However `Object.keys` returns an array already, so why would you need to transform it to use `forEach`?

Comment: There's no `asArray()` function in `Array`

Comment: @gforce301 - my bad. Looks like I copied and applied the code without understanding the syntaxes appropriately.

Comment: Note that tag [tag:javascript]  usage guideline at the top explicitly  excludes google-apps-script probably because gas doesn't support ES6(support for which is in alpha for select consumers)

Comment: @TheMaster - my bad! Hadn't noticed it. Have removed it now. Will ensure not to combine these going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES5,

```js
var arr1 = [
  {
    date: '2019-01-01',
    marks: [
      {
        quantity: {
          shoes: 1,
          belt: 2,
          socks: 3,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-02',
    marks: [
      {
        quantity: {
          shoes: 4,
          belt: 5,
          socks: 6,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
var out = [];
arr1.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.marks.forEach(function(mark) {
    out.push({
      values: [obj.date].concat(
        Object.keys(mark.quantity).map(function(key) {
          return mark.quantity[key];
        })
      ),
    });
  });
});
console.log({ rows: out });
```

Comment: This worked perfectly in Apps Script editor :) Just made a tiny modification with the date `...  values: ['"' + obj.date + '"'].concat(  ...`. Needed the date in a string format.

Comment: @Sourabh it's already in string format. You're adding extra double quotes to the date string, which will cause problems down the road.

Comment: Understood. Will experiment and refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array of keys for the order and flatmap the marks array.

```js
var data = [{ date: "2019-01-01", marks: [{ quantity: { shoes: 1, belt: 2, socks: 3 } }] }, { date: "2019-01-02", marks: [{ quantity: { shoes: 4, belt: 5, socks: 6 } }] }],
    keys = ['shoes', 'belt', 'socks'],
    rows = data.map(({ date, marks }) =>
        ({ values: [date, ...marks.flatMap(({ quantity }) => keys.map(k => quantity[k]))] })),
    result = { rows };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This looks like it could work; although, any way not to get the `rows` & `values` in double quotes?

Comment: this is only a visual appearance here. the keys do not have quotes.

Comment: Looks like the `=>` format is still not supported via Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list=[{"date":"2019-01-01","marks":[{"quantity":{"shoes":1,"belt":2,"socks":3}}]},{"date":"2019-01-02","marks":[{"quantity":{"shoes":4,"belt":5,"socks":6}}]}];

let result = list.map(( {date, marks} ) => { return {value: [date, ...Object.values(marks[0].quantity)]};});
let wrap = {rows: result};
console.log(wrap);
```

Comment: I see that you've not added the double quotes on `values` but the result still shows it with `"`. Any way to avoid them?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = products.map(p=>{
     return p.marks.reduce((t,m)=>{
        t.push({ values: [p.date, ...Object.entries(m.quantity).map(([key, value]) => value)]})
        return t;
      },[])
  }
).flat(2)

console.log(x)
```

Comment: Also in one line: ```products.map(p=>(p.marks.map(m=>({ values: [p.date, ...Object.entries(m.quantity).map(([key, value]) => value)]})))).flat(2)```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.